# CI/CD pipelines with Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, devops, docker-swarm, cicd, bitbucket-pipelines

We have a pretty simple Single Host Docker Swarm set up

1. A docker compose file to manage all of our services. The latest services are tagged as latest. We don't use versioning yet because our dev process is quite rapid.
2. A single host where we have the docker compose file.
3. On pushes to main branch we run a bitbucket pipeline to ssh into our server vm and run docker stack deploy for our compose files with registry auth.

When we perform a lot of merges simultaneously,  we run into the following issue:

```
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = update out of sequence
```

What should we do to avoid this?